# Connect to client behind the router - Inactivity timeout [OpenVPN, Juniper SRX210H]

Tags: vpn, juniper-srx

I have such topology:

[image]

I want to make a VPN connection from client in subnet 192.x.x.x to my OpenVPN server. But still getting such messages:

```
Mon Mar 10 16:24:00 2014 Initialization Sequence Completed
Mon Mar 10 16:26:00 2014 [OpenVPNServerTEST] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Mon Mar 10 16:26:00 2014 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Mon Mar 10 16:26:00 2014 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Mon Mar 10 16:26:00 2014 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 LZO compression initialized
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:166 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 Socket Buffers: R=[229376->131072] S=[229376->131072]
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:1450 EF:58 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '9e7066d2'
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '162b04de'
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Mar 10 16:26:02 2014 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]172.16.1.111:1194
Mon Mar 10 16:27:02 2014 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Mon Mar 10 16:27:02 2014 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Mon Mar 10 16:27:02 2014 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Mon Mar 10 16:27:02 2014 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Mon Mar 10 16:27:02 2014 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 NOTE: OpenVPN 2.1 requires '--script-security 2' or higher to call user-defined scripts or executables
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 Re-using SSL/TLS context
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 LZO compression initialized
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:166 EF:66 EB:0 ET:0 EL:0 ]
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 Socket Buffers: R=[229376->131072] S=[229376->131072]
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1558 D:1450 EF:58 EB:135 ET:0 EL:0 AF:3/1 ]
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 Local Options hash (VER=V4): '9e7066d2'
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 Expected Remote Options hash (VER=V4): '162b04de'
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Mon Mar 10 16:27:04 2014 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]172.16.1.111:1194
^C (CTRL+C)
Mon Mar 10 16:27:20 2014 event_wait : Interrupted system call (code=4)
Mon Mar 10 16:27:20 2014 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
Mon Mar 10 16:27:20 2014 /sbin/route del -net 10.8.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.255
Mon Mar 10 16:27:20 2014 /sbin/route del -net 172.16.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
Mon Mar 10 16:27:20 2014 /sbin/route del -net 172.16.254.0 netmask 255.255.255.0
Mon Mar 10 16:27:20 2014 Closing TUN/TAP interface
Mon Mar 10 16:27:20 2014 /sbin/ifconfig tun0 0.0.0.0
```

My clients (all of them) are Xubuntu 13.10 with **iptables rules:**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination       
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW udp dpt:openvpn
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination       
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere           
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination       
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

1. My client from the subnet 192.x.x.x is client3 - it cant connect to
   vpn server
2. Clients from subnet 172.x.x.x are client1 and client2 - they can
   connect with OpenVPN server with no problems.
3. My router is JSRX 210 H with out of the box configuration - without
   VPN client3 (192.x.x.x) can ping client1, client2 and server
       from subnet 172.x.x.x. (everyone can ping everyone without vpn =
       full connectivity)

**My client3 (192.x.x.x) config file:**

```
client
dev tun0
proto udp
remote 172.16.1.111 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
# Downgrade privileges after initialization (non-Windows only)
;user nobody
;group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/client3test.crt
key /etc/openvpn/client3test.key
tls-auth /etc/openvpn/ta.key 1
cipher AES-256-CBC
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Config files for client1 and client2 are the same (despite the tun, client1 uses tun0, client2 uses tun1), my every client uses its own key and certificate.

**My server config file:**

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun0
ca ca.crt
cert OpenVPNServerTEST.crt
key OpenVPNServerTEST.key 
dh dh.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 172.16.254.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 172.16.1.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
tls-auth ta.key 0
cipher AES-256-CBC   # AES
comp-lzo
;user nobody
;group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
log-append  openvpn.log
verb 3
```

**JSRX config file:** http://pastie.org/private/gcnclsztzwnbglzvcalhla

Comment: You're tagging this question with juniper-srx but AFAICT the juniper isn't terminating the vpn.  Why did you tag this question with juniper-srx?

Comment: @MikePennington♦ because I thought that its the JSRX issue, if not - whats wrong? Added JSRX config